# How to display rich text in tooltip ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, tooltip, richtext

I use the following code to display a tooltip

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="datefu" HeaderText="date" 
            SortExpression="datefu" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="title" SortExpression="titlefu">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("titlefu") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

        <a href="#" title="<asp:Literal ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fu") %>'/>"/>



        <asp:Label ID="NamePatientLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("titlefu") %>' />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

display the following result

[image]

however when i edit the text as follows (making it bold and red in another gridview containing rich text editor)

i get the following (as a formatting result in the second grid view)

[image]

however when i view in the first gridview to display the tooltip i get the following reult

[image]

i really need your help to display the tooltip as rich text

although many people say that jquery is "very easy", please let me know if you have a solution other than jquery.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us more about your hard time with jquery in detail, because i'm not aware of a tool which is easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

[How to use AJAX tooltip control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625397/how-to-use-telerik-tooltip-control)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the browser's native tooltip but implement some kind of balloon tip. There are many ways to do this, this page shows 12 ways in jquery http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/05/12-jquery-tooltip-for-web-developer.html

A simple example with [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/attributes) is to add an attribute named tooltip to all your a-hrefs containing your text and executing this jquery startup script

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $('#content a[tooltip]').each(function()
   {
      $(this).qtip(
      {
         content: $(this).attr('tooltip')
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: although many people say that jquery is "very easy", i have really HARD TIME using it and i tried more than 10 times, always failed to make any use of it. i know it is my bad, but if you know other way not jquery plz tell me.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [HoverMenuExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/HoverMenu/HoverMenu.aspx) in the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/). Despite the name it doesn't just display menus - you can use it to do popups. I just used it to do something similar to what you want to do.
e.g.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptmanager" />
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="2"
        CellSpacing="2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server" />
                    <ajaxtoolkit:HoverMenuExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="Label1" PopupControlID="PopupPanel"
                        ID="hme" PopupPosition="Right" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Panel ID="PopupPanel" runat="server" BackColor="White">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text="Some text" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```