# How to use AJAX tooltip control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik, tooltip

i need help in using AJAX tooltip control to display dynamic fields

the database table contains

ID --> Autonumber

Title --> text

Date --> Date

Notes --> Memo (rich text)

database is Microsoft access (.mdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will find what you are searching for here  -http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tooltip/examples/bindtotarget/defaultcs.aspx. Follow the description and sample code to understand how to configure your tooltip.